# Material UI: How to change slider thumb visibility when user interacts with the slider, i.e. changes the slider value?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, slider

I have a Material UI Slider in my application. I want to keep a thumb invisible until the user changes the slider value. When the slider is used, I want a thumb to stay visible at the value that users sets. Using the `active` CSS property, I managed to hide the thumb and show it only while the user uses it, which is while the slider is dragged by finger or mouse pointer. When the interaction stops, I want it to stay at the chosen value, but it disappears.

1. Initial state
   [image]
2. Slider is interaced with (dragged)
   [image]
3. Finished interaction
   [image]

I tried adding another, duplicated slider, with thumb component visible all the time and then tried to conditionally render one of the sliders depending on the value (`value ? <Slider1 /> : <Slider2 />`), but it worked to some extent. Thumb was always set to the beggining of slider, independently from the value.

Any ideas? Thanks.

For code samples, refer to material ui slider API.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using withStyles(), import withStyles and the Slider:

```
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
```

then customize your Slider, something like this:

```
export const CustomizedSlider = withStyles({
  thumb: {
    height: 28,
    width: 28,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    marginTop: -14,
    marginLeft: -14,
    "&:hover, &$active": {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    },
  },
})(Slider);
```

The default color should be "transparent" and It will change to "red" when the mouse hovers it. More about withStyles() [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/). Hope this helps you!.

code reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/slider/CustomizedSlider.js